# using mutt to send mail with two messages

Tags: bash, mutt

I would like to use mutt for sending an email with two messages inside, it the folloring code it runs for ones content saved in a file named forescast

```
mutt -s "forecast temperature" mail.account < forecast.csv
```

it works, but if I want to send as a content in the same mail, two messages, another file.csv or .dat, and etc..., it doesn't work, any idea using mutt? is it possible? for example, the following code does't send the second content

```
mutt -s "forecast temperature" mail.account < forecast.csv increments.csv
```

Comment: See: [mutt command with multiple attachments in single mail unix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17342450/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this works?

```
cat forecast.csv increments.csv | mutt -s "forecast temperature" mail.account
```

Answer (score 1):

`mutt`'s `-i` option exists to specify a file to include into the body of a message.
You can use it along with redirecting a second file.

`mutt -s 'subject' -i file1.txt < file2.txt -- johndoe@example.com`